# Como unir vários arquivos texto em um só?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, diretório

Alguém sabe como fazer pra selecionar todos os arquivos texto de um mesmo diretório e juntar as informações de todos eles em apenas um arquivo texto final?

Exemplo: Na pasta X, tenho os arquivos 1.txt, 2.txt e 3.txt. Preciso juntar o conteúdo de todos em apenas um arquivo texto.

Tentei esse código, que compila mas quando executa é levantada uma excepção do tipo IndexOutofRange.

```
string[] stringArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\InventX", "*.txt");
        System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= stringArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(stringArray[i]));
        }
        string bulidOutput = stringBuilder.ToString();
        string newFilePath = @"C:\Lala.txt";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newFilePath, bulidOutput);
```

Answer (score 10):

O erro no seu código deve-se a esta condição:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= stringArray.Count(); i++)
```

deveria ser

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Count(); i++)
```

Como está, na ultima iteração, quando `i == stringArray.Count()` e dado que os `arrays` são **índice zero** irá levantar a excepção `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Para acrescentar, uma forma eficiente de unir os ficheiros é lê-los bocado a bocado e ir escrevendo à medida que cada bocado é lido. Pode alterar o tamanho do *buffer* e ir comparando os ganhos/perdas relativamente à performance para perceber qual se adequa melhor ao seu cenário.

```
public void UnirFicheiros(string directorio, string filtro, string ficheiroUnido)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(directorio))
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();

    const int bufferSize = 1 * 1024;
    using (var outputFile = File.Create(Path.Combine(directorio, ficheiroUnido)))
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directorio, filtro))
        {
            using (var inputFile = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    outputFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Aqui vai um exemplo simples:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string diretorio = @"C:\teste";

    String[] listaDeArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(diretorio);

    if (listaDeArquivos.Length > 0)
    {
        string caminhoArquivoDestino = @"C:\teste\saida.txt";

        FileStream arquivoDestino = File.Open(caminhoArquivoDestino, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        arquivoDestino.Close();

        List<String> linhasDestino = new List<string>();

        foreach (String caminhoArquivo in listaDeArquivos)
        {
            linhasDestino.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo));
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(caminhoArquivoDestino, linhasDestino.ToArray());
    }

}
```

Brinque com os métodos e os adeque a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 8):

Como a abordagem não parece ser boa, resolvi fazer um exemplo compilável que resolvesse o problema de uma forma genérica.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Util.IO;

public class MergeFiles {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        int bufferSize;
        FileUtil.MergeTextFiles(args[0], args[1], args[2], (int.TryParse(args[3], out bufferSize) ? bufferSize : 0));
    }
}

namespace Util.IO {
    public static class FileUtil {
        public static void MergeTextFiles(string targetFileName, string sourcePath, string searchPattern = "*.*", int bufferSize = 0) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourcePath)) {
            sourcePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        }
            if (targetFileName.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) != -1) {
                throw new ArgumentException("Diretório fonte especificado contém caracteres inválidos", "sourcePath");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetFileName)) {
                throw new ArgumentException("Nome do arquivo destino precisa ser especificado", "targetFileName");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetFileName)) {
                throw new ArgumentException("Nome do arquivo destino precisa ser especificado", "targetFileName");
            }
            if (targetFileName.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) != -1) {
                throw new ArgumentException("Nome do arquivo destino contém caracteres inválidos", "targetFileName");
            }
            var targetFullFileName = Path.Combine(sourcePath, targetFileName);
            if (bufferSize == 0) {
                File.Delete(targetFullFileName);
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern)) {
                    if (file != targetFullFileName) {
                        File.AppendAllText(targetFullFileName, File.ReadAllText(file));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                using (var targetFile = File.Create(targetFullFileName, bufferSize)) {
                    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern)) {
                        if (file != targetFullFileName) {
                            using (var sourceFile = File.OpenRead(file))    {
                                var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                                int bytesRead;
                                while ((bytesRead = sourceFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                                    targetFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/JoinFiles.cs).

Em versões mais novas dá para reduzir esse código.

O método `Main()` está aí só para facilitar um teste rápido, não está em condições de produção. O método `MergeTextFiles()` está bem razoável para uso. Não está 100%, não fiz uma unidade de testes para ele, não documentei, não pensei em todas as situações possíveis, mas já está bem encaminhado.

Você pode escolher um tamanho de *buffer* se quiser controlar melhor a forma de cópia. Se achar que nunca vai precisar disto, pode tirar esta parte do método. Mas não faz mal deixar, já que o padrão é fazer a cópia integral dos arquivos dentro dos critérios do da implementação corrente do .NET.

## Melhorias possíveis

Algumas melhorias podem ser feitas para deixar mais genérico ainda ou adicionar funcionalidades. Você poderia, por exemplo, colocar um último parâmetro parâmetro `extraNewLineOptions extraNewLineOption = extraNewLineOptions.NoExtraNewLine` e uma enumeração `enum extraNewLineOptions { NoExtraNewLine, SelectiveExtraNewLine, AlwaysExtraNewLine }`.

Para permitir que uma quebra de linha extra possa ser colocada no final de cada arquivo para garantir que não vá encavalar textos. Isto pode ser útil mas na maioria dos casos não é necessário, por isso ele ficaria desabilitado por *default*. Deixo para a criatividade de cada um a implementação disso, principalmente pelo `SelectiveExtraNewLine()` que só colocaria uma quebra de linha se não existe no final do arquivo, não é tão trivial implementar. É possível criar um *overload* para melhorar o uso dos parâmetros.

Outra melhoria é permitir que a cópia seja feita de forma assíncrona. Muito útil se tiver grandes volumes de arquivos.

E o método poderia ser quebrando em partes também.

#### Dependendo da versão do .NET

Usei recursos para poder rodar em praticamente qualquer versão do .NET. Se for garantido que será usado em versões mais recentes, é possível trocar as verificações de parâmetros por `Contract.Requires()`. Ou até é possível retirar tudo isso já que a verificação de todos esses problemas também são feitas nos métodos chamados. Claro que você perderia a localidade da informação de onde exatamente originou o erro.

Infelizmente não há um método público para verificar a validade do coringa antecipadamente. Mas se for necessário é possível verificar [como é implementado nos fontes do .NET](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs#b949d580e3b5631a) (e possivelmente nos [fontes do Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/SourceCodeRepository) também ([no .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Path.cs,090eca8621a248ee)).

Se você tiver o C# 6 (através do [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)), algumas melhorias poderão ser feitas.

Poderia usar um `using Util.IO.FileUtil;` e depois chamar o método diretamente: `MergeTextFiles("combo.txt", ".", "*.txt")`.

Além disso as declarações `int bufferSize;` no método `Main()` e `int bytesRead;` poderiam ser feitas *inline* durante a sua utilização durante o `TryParse()` e o `while` respectivamente: `int.TryParse(args[3], out var bufferSize` e `while ((int bytesRead = sourceFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {`.

Veja o [exemplo em C# 6 no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xCxs5D). E [no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RuUsLf). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/AutoProperty.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Com [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
String[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(@".\Txts", "*.txt");
StreamWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter(".\\Final.txt");
foreach (String arquivo in arquivos)
{
    strWriter.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(arquivo));
}
strWriter.Flush();
strWriter.Dispose();
```

*Referência:*

- [StreamWriter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Directory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)