# Como agrupar códigos e somar quantidades existentes em arquivos texto com C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo

Tenho vários arquivos texto dentro de um diretório. Preciso fazer em C# e unir todos os arquivos texto em um arquivo texto final, porém tratando o conteúdo deles.

Exemplo:

```
Arq1.txt
123456010
654321020

Arq2.txt
123456040
654321005
```

Os 6 primeiros caracteres são um código e os 3 caracteres finais são a quantidade.
Preciso unir os arquivos de alguma forma que seja gerado um arquivo final contemplando os códigos, sem repeti-los e somando as quantidades.

```
ArqFinal.txt
123456050
654321025
```

Desculpem não colocar códigos, mas eu realmente não tenho ideia.

Comment: Você conhece expressões regulares?

Comment: Olá Cigano. Não conheço, mas por vc ter citado comecei a pesquisar. Já consigo separar e identificar os campos, em teoria.

Comment: Se todos os números estiverem alinhados, basta usar divisão em substrings, de uma maneira bem simples e sem a necessidade de regex.

Comment: @Bacco sim, eles estão "alinhados", ou seja, a quantidade de caracteres do campo código sempre será 6 (os seis primeiros) e a quantidade de caracteres do campo código será sempre 3 (os três ultimos). Vou pesquisar a divisão.

Comment: @Vhox realmente é caso pra substring. Você pode armazenar o ID de 6 digitos como key em uma array, e ir somando os valores nesta array. Só não vou me aventurar a escrever o código, pois não uso C#.

Comment: @DBX8 sem conhecer detalhes da linguagem, eu extrairia ID e QTD, e faria algo assim: if index ID nao existe na array, cria a entrada ID com valor QTD, senão, soma QTD no valor do ID já existente. depois de feita a leitura de todos os txts, geraria a saída. Esse approach só seria problemático se os txts fossem gigantescos.

Comment: Agradeço a todos. Esse está bem dificil pra mim, mas vou continuar tentando. Caso tenham sugestoes e ajudas, sao mais do q bem vindas. Abs!

Answer (score 6):

Adaptei a [resposta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16739/101) para esse caso. Não pensei em todas as possibilidades. Você não deu critérios para resolver problemas de má formação do arquivo, se há como validar os códigos e o que acontece se a quantidade não contiver um valor numérico válido.

Considerei que está implícito que os valores da quantidade são sempre inteiros e que uma valor inválido seria considerado como zero. Também considerei que o mínimo que uma linha deve ter de validação é o tamanho exato de 9 caracteres.

Usei uma estrutura de dados auxiliar para colocar na memória todos os códigos através de chaves únicas e somando as quantidades nos códigos já existentes.

Fiz um teste rápido e está apresentando o resultado esperado. O código certamente pode ser melhor organizado.

Os comentários estão sendo usados apenas para fins didáticos e não reflete o meu estilo de codificação.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MergeFiles {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var caminhoOrigem = @"C:\teste";
        var nomeArquivoCompleto = @"C:\teste\saida.txt";
        var itens = new Dictionary<string, int>(); //Cria a estrutura que permite chaves únicas do tipo string e valores associados do tipo int
        int resultado;
        foreach (var arquivo in Directory.GetFiles(caminhoOrigem, "*.txt")) { //Pega todos os arquivos com extensão txt disponíveis no diretório
            if (arquivo != nomeArquivoCompleto) { //Não deixa processar o próprio arquivo que está sendo criado
                foreach (var linha in File.ReadAllLines(arquivo)) { //Lê todas as linhas individualmente de cada arquivo
                    if (linha.Length == 9) { //Garante que a linha tem 9 caracteres
                        var chave = linha.Substring(0, 6); //Pega os 6 primeiros caracteres
                        var valor = (int.TryParse(linha.Substring(6, 3), out resultado) ? resultado : 0); //Pega os 3 caracteres seguintes e converte para numérico
                        if (itens.ContainsKey(chave)) { //verifica se já existe a chave no dicionário
                            itens[chave] = itens[chave] + valor; //adiciona o valor obtido na linha à chave já existe no dicionário
                        } else {
                            itens.Add(chave, valor); //Adiciona uma nova chave ainda inexistente no dicionário
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Cria o arquivo destino adicionando todas as linhas do dicionário recriando a mesma estrutura anterior através do LINQ
        File.WriteAllLines(nomeArquivoCompleto, itens.Select(item => item.Key + item.Value.ToString("000")).ToArray());
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Join2.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Certamente esta thread é continuação deste ([Como unir vários arquivos texto em um só?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16704/como-unir-varios-arquivos-texto-em-um-so)
), então vou usar o código postado pelo @reiksiel para complementar o exemplo:

Bom, como você mesmo disse, a quantidade é representanda pelo os 3 últimos dígitos, logo podemos usar de um Dictionary onde este ID seria a chave e caso já exista este ID no dicionario você vai somando para logo em seguida exportar para o .txt, algo como isso:

```
Dictionary<string, int> valores = new Dictionary<string, int>();

string diretorio = @"C:\teste";

string[] listaDeArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(diretorio);

if (listaDeArquivos.Length > 0)
{
    string caminhoArquivoDestino = @"C:\teste\saida.txt";

    FileStream arquivoDestino = File.Open(caminhoArquivoDestino, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

    arquivoDestino.Close();

    List<string> linhasDestino = new List<string>();

    foreach (string caminhoArquivo in listaDeArquivos)
    {
         foreach (var linhaArquivoAtual in File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo))
         {
            string id = linhaArquivoAtual.Substring(0, linhaArquivoAtual.Length - 3);
            string quantidade = linhaArquivoAtual.Substring(linhaArquivoAtual.Length - 3, 3);

            if (valores.ContainsKey(id)) 
                valores[id] = valores[id] + Convert.ToInt32(quantidade);
            else
                valores.Add(id, Convert.ToInt32(quantidade));           

         }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(caminhoArquivoDestino, valores.Select(x => x.Key + x.Valeu.ToString("000")).ToArray());
}
```

Não consegui testar este código acima pois estou sem Visual Studio, mas seria algo deste gênero.

Comment: Olá Vitor. Agradeço a sua atenção. Vou testar!

Comment: Vitor, se possivel vc pode me esclarecer a que vc kis se referir nakele if com "valores"? q valores? Desculpe o amadorismo. Abs.

Comment: Claro @Vhox, valores é uma variável para aquele dicionario onde a chave principal é um string e o valor da chave é um inteiro, é verificado se já existe uma chave neste dicionario (123456), caso não exista é adicionado ele no dicionario, porem se ele existir, eu recupero o valor e somo a quantidade nova com a anterior.

Comment: Cara, logica sensacional. Tentei fazer os testes aqui e ta dando o seguinte erro: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Vhox corrigi o código, o erro estava nesta linha (         valores[id] = valores[id].Value + Convert.ToInt32(quantidade)), a propriedade .Valeu não existe quando se acessa diretamente pelo idnex do dicionario, era só remover o .Value

Comment: Vitor, mto obrigado! O codigo ficou excelente.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] arrayFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.txt");
string outputFile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ArquivoSaida.txt";
Dictionary<string, int> values = new Dictionary<string, int>();

   if (File.Exists(outputFile))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("O arquivo de saída existe!");
      Console.ReadLine();
      Environment.Exit(0);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < arrayFiles.Count(); i++)
   {
      foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(arrayFiles[i]))
      {
         string id  = Regex.Match(line, @"[0-9]...{3}").Value;
         string qtd = Regex.Match(line, @"[0-9]..\z{3}").Value;

      if (values.ContainsKey(id))
         values[id] = values[id] + Convert.ToInt32(qtd);
      else
         values.Add(id, Convert.ToInt32(qtd));  
       }
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(outputFile , values.Select(x => x.Key + x.Value).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Procedimento realizado, Pressione alguma tecla para sair...");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Isso vai procurar por todos os arquivos de texto no atual diretório de trabalho, se o arquivo de saída existir, o programa vai emitir uma mensagem dizendo que o arquivo existe e ira finalizar o programa. Diferente das outras ótimas respostas em que é utilizado o método [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), nesse código é abordado o uso de [**expressões regulares**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), expressões simples, porém funcionais no teste que realizei.

```
txtfile1.txt
   123456010
   654321020
txtfile2.txt
   123456040
   654321005
txtfile3.txt
   123456080
   654321007
ArquivoSaida.txt
   123456130
   65432132
```

Graças @Bacco !

Answer (score 1):

Usando FileHelpers isso parece que não será muito complicado.

Classe do layout dos registros que contém o código e a quantidade:

```
public class Registro
{
    [FieldFixedLength(6)]
    public int Codigo {get; set; }

    [FieldFixedLength(3)]
    public int Quantidade {get; set; }
}

using FileHelpers;

// Realiza todo o processamento. Observe os métodos abaixo para entender o código.
public void CombinarRegistros(List<string> listaDeArquivos)
{
    var listaDeRegistros = new List<Registro>();

    foreach (var arquivo in listaDeArquivos)
    {
        listaDeArquivos.AddRange(ObtenhaRegistros(arquivo));
    }

    var registrosCombinados = CombineQuantidades(listaDeRegistros);

    EscrevaArquivoDosRegistrosCombinados("ArquivoFinal.txt", registrosCombinados);
}

// Lê os registros dos arquivos originais.
public List<Registro>() ObtenhaRegistros(string nomeDoArquivo)
{
    var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(Registro));

    var linhasDoArquivo = engine.ReadFile(nomeDoArquivo);

    var listaDeRegistros = new List<Registro>();

    foreach (var linha in linhasDoArquivo)
    {
        lista.Add((Registro)linha);
    }

    return listaDeRegistros;
}

// Combina a quantidade dos registros.
public List<Registro>() CombineQuantidades(List<Registro> registros)
{
    return registros.GroupBy(x => x.Codigo).Select(y => new Registro
    {
        Codigo = y.First().Codigo,
        Quantidade = y.Sum(z => z.Quantidade)
    }).ToList();
}

// Escreve os registros combinados somando a quantidade em um único arquivo.
public void EscrevaArquivoDosRegistrosCombinados(string nomeDoArquivoDeDestino, registros)
{
    MultiRecordEngine engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(Registro));

    engine.AppendToFile(nomeDoArquivoDeDestino, registros);
}
```