# Como agrupar arquivo texto de acordo com parâmetros da primeiro linha em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo

Consegui juntar diversos arquivos texto de um mesmo diretório em um arquivo texto final, agrupando os códigos iguais e somando as suas respectivas quantidades, utilizando o seguinte código (créditos ao amigo Vitor Mendes):

```
Dictionary<string, int> valores = new Dictionary<string, int>();

string diretorio = @"C:\teste";

string[] listaDeArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(diretorio);

if (listaDeArquivos.Length > 0)
{
    string caminhoArquivoDestino = @"C:\teste\saida.txt";

    FileStream arquivoDestino = File.Open(caminhoArquivoDestino, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

    arquivoDestino.Close();

    List<string> linhasDestino = new List<string>();

    foreach (string caminhoArquivo in listaDeArquivos)
    {
         foreach (var linhaArquivoAtual in File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo))
         {
            string id = linhaArquivoAtual.Substring(0, linhaArquivoAtual.Length - 3);
            string quantidade = linhaArquivoAtual.Substring(linhaArquivoAtual.Length - 3, 3);

            if (valores.ContainsKey(id)) 
            valores[id] = valores[id] + Convert.ToInt32(quantidade);
            else
            valores.Add(id, Convert.ToInt32(quantidade));           

         }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(caminhoArquivoDestino, valores.Select(x => x.Key + x.Valeu.ToString("000")).ToArray());
}
```

A primeira linha de casa arquivo texto contem 2 parâmetros de identificação separados por ponto. Vou exemplificar:

```
Conteúdo do Arq1.txt
000032;30032014
123456010
654321020

Conteúdo do Arq2.txt
000032;30032014
123456005
654321005

Conteúdo do Arq3.txt
000033;23052014
123456050
654321020

Conteúdo do Arq4.txt
000033;23052014
123456020
654321005

Conteúdo do Arq5.txt
000033;20052014
123456001
654321002

Conteúdo do Arq6.txt
000033;20052014
123456009
654321008
```

Ao agrupar esses arquivos, o programa deverá gerar diferentes arquivos finais de acordo com os parâmetros da primeira linha. Nesses exemplos de arquivos, o resultado final serão os seguintes arquivos:

```
ArqFinal00003320052014.txt
123456010
654321010

ArqFinal00003323052014.txt
123456070
654321025

ArqFinal00003230032014.txt
123456015
654321025
```

Ou seja, o programa deverá agrupar os arquivos de acordo com a primeira linha, criando arquivos finais diferentes.

Comment: O arquivo deverá ser com o parâmetro da primeira linha sem o ';'?

Comment: poderia explicar como seria o agrupamento pelos parâmetros? como o sistema tem q reconhecer que o arquivo faz parte de um grupo ou de outro

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Sim, o nome final sim. Até porque eu nao sei se é possível nomear algum arquivo utilizando o caracter ";"

Comment: @TafarelChicotti o agrupamento é pela primeira linha. O programa só soma os arquivos q tiverem a primeira linha iguais. Por isso gera varios arquivos finais. No caso de 3 arkivos, 2 com a primeira linha iguais e 1 nao, serao gerados 2 arkivos finais: 1 com a soma dos arkivos com a primeira linha iguais e 1 com o arkivo que possui a primeira linha diferente.

Answer (score 6):

Conforme exemplo [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16758/101), um dicionário é a solução para agrupar itens. No caso agora você tem dois níveis de agrupamento, então o uso de dicionários aninhados se faz necessário. Você tem o dicionário com os nomes dos arquivos como chave e o valor é um outro dicionário com códigos como chave e as quantidades como valor.

O código está longe de estar ótimo mas ele está testado e faz o que você deseja.

Os comentários foram colocados para fins didáticos e não exprime a maneira como eu comento códigos.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MergeFiles {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var itens = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>(); //Cria a estrutura que permite chaves únicas do tipo string e valores associados do tipo int
        int resultado;
        foreach (var arquivo in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\teste", "*.txt")) { //Pega todos os arquivos com extensão txt disponíveis no diretório
            var chaveArquivo = "";
            foreach (var linha in File.ReadAllLines(arquivo)){ //Lê todas as linhas individualmente de cada arquivo
                if (linha.Substring(6, 1)  == ";") { //Verifica se esta é a primeira linha
                   chaveArquivo = linha.Substring(0, 6) + linha.Substring(7, 8); //Pega os 6 primeiros caracteres e os 8 sequintes pulando o ;
                    if (!itens.ContainsKey(chaveArquivo)) { //verifica se não existe a chave com nome do arquivo
                        itens.Add(chaveArquivo, new Dictionary<string, int>()); //Adiciona uma nova chave ainda inexistente no dicionário
                    }
                } else {
                    var chave = linha.Substring(0, 6); //Pega os 6 primeiros caracteres
                    var valor = (int.TryParse(linha.Substring(6, 3), out resultado) ? resultado : 0); //Pega os 3 caracteres seguintes e converte para numérico
                    if (itens[chaveArquivo].ContainsKey(chave)) { //verifica se já existe a chave no dicionário
                        itens[chaveArquivo][chave] = itens[chaveArquivo][chave] + valor; //adiciona o valor obtido na linha à chave já existe no dicionário
                    } else {
                        itens[chaveArquivo].Add(chave, valor); //Adiciona uma nova chave ainda inexistente no dicionário
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Cria os arquivos agrupados adicionando todas as linhas do dicionário recriando a mesma estrutura anterior através do LINQ
        foreach(var arquivo in itens) {
            File.WriteAllLines(arquivo.Key + ".txt", arquivo.Value.Select(item => item.Key + item.Value.ToString("000")).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Join3.cs)

Comment: Ola @bigown muito obrigado pela sua atenção. Vou testar o seu codigo, mas pelo que vi vc mudou o restante dos parametros nao eh? A verificacao da primeira linha é apenas para agrupar arquivos texto que tem a primeira linha iguais e com isso gerar diversos arkivos de saida diferentes. A minha dificuldade está nisso. O restante da operação jah esta funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Se você já tem algo próximo de estar pronto, poste esse código. O que você postou nem começa fazer o que você diz que precisa. O código acima foi testado com os dados que você passou e produz exatamente os resultados que você apresentou. Se não é isso que você precisa, então é preciso explicar melhor. Até onde eu percebo, estou te dando a solução pronta em um código bem organizado para o curto tempo que tive para fazê-lo.

Comment: O código que eu postei funciona perfeitamente. Oq eu preciso é apenas a diferenciação dos arquivos pela leitura da primeira linha, ou seja, é uma função a se acrescentar no código que já funciona. Acho que não precisava uma resposta tão ríspida, mas eu agradeço o seu tempo gasto de toda forma.

Comment: Se ele funciona perfeitamente, você não precisa de ajuda. Você pode dizer que ele está compilando, mas não faz absolutamente nada do que você está dizendo que precisa. Se ele não faz o **exatamente** o que você está precisando, ele não funciona perfeitamente. Se você não está contente com a ajuda que está recebendo aqui, você também pode contratar um profissional.

Comment: Certo Bigown, muito obrigado. =)

Comment: Não sei se eu que não entendi algo da conversa aqui, mas o código postado na questão não é nem parecido com o necessário pra resolver o problema proposto, muito menos com uma "simples adaptação". Pra diferenciar os arquivos, creio que a solução que foi apresentada na resposta é fundamental para atender o que foi proposto na pergunta.

Comment: Olá @Bacco. O código que eu postei serve para juntar os arquivos de uma mesma pasta. Para isso o código funciona corretamente. Agora oq eu preciso é de uma função nova nele, para que ele separe os arquivos texto de acordo com a primeira linha dos mesmos antes de juntar.

Comment: Bom, reli aqui os comentários e suas perguntas anteriores. Confirme pra mim então se é isso: o que você quer não é apenas uma solução para o problema, mas sim que alguém pegue o código que você pôs na pergunta, e adapte para você, seria isto?

Comment: Olá @Bacco. Editei o código e coloquei exatamente o que eu utilizo.

Comment: Sugeriria você trocar o `x.Valeu` da última linha do código que você exatamente utiliza por `x.Value`, pra evitar algum possível problema.

Comment: @Bacco eu dei a solução para o problema. Peguei os 6 arquivos de exemplo que estão na pergunta, rodei este código e gerou 3 arquivos exatamente com os valores que ele apresentou na pergunta. O resultado é exato ao que ele diz querer. Se o código não tem exatamente a construção que ele deseja, aí complica. Para ter um código escrito com cada vírgula que ele acha melhor, tem que contratar alguém para fazer isso por ele. Se ele recusa o código que dá a solução, não posso fazer mais nada. Ou será que eu sou obrigado a escrever o código no estilo que cada usuário deseja?

Comment: @bigown até por isso que acabei fazendo [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16818/#comment31593_16867), pois a impressão que me deu é que não se trata de simplesmente solucionar o problema, mas sim de usar o código que o OP se "simpatizou". Não que ele não tenha o direito de se simpatizar com algum código, mas é realmente complicado esperar que o site funcione "à la carte". Talvez o autor da outra resposta (a do "valeu") queira fazer o ajuste, quem sabe...

Comment: Agradeço a atenção de vocês, pessoal. E peço desculpas por algo que eu possa ter dito que não agradou. Em momento algum quis ser mal agradecido. Abraços!

Answer (score 3):

Usando o código da pergunta, deveria ficar da seguinte forma:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string diretorio = @"C:\teste";

    String[] listaDeArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(diretorio);

    if (listaDeArquivos.Length > 0)
    {

        FileStream arquivoDestino = File.Open(caminhoArquivoDestino, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        arquivoDestino.Close();

        String[] linhasDestino;

        Dictionary<String, List<String>> out = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();

        foreach (String caminhoArquivo in listaDeArquivos)
        {
            linhasDestino = File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo);
            String name = linhasDestino[0].replace(';','');
            if (!out.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                out[name] = new List<String>();
            }
            for(int i = 1; i < linhasDestino.Length; i++)
            {
                out[name].Add(linhasDestino[i]);
            }
        }

        foreach(String key in out.Keys)
        {
            string caminhoArquivoDestino = @"C:\teste\"+key;
            File.WriteAllLines(caminhoArquivoDestino, out[key].ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Estou sem compilador aqui, mas isso deve funcionar. O que é feito é o seguinte:

1. Abre o arquivo;
2. Para cada arquivo aberto, ele vê se já existe uma entrada com aquele nome da primeira linha do arquivo;
3. Adiciona todas as linhas (a partir da segunda) à uma lista associada aquele nome;
4. Depois escreve todas as linhas em arquivos com os nomes associados.

Basicamente, a ideia do algoritmo é essa.

Comment: Obrigado, Felipe. Vou testar. Basicamente, o que o software tem q fazer é agrupar/somar os arkivos onde a primeira linha é igual.