# Comparação de arquivos

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, diretório

Preciso comparar arquivos de diretórios diferentes e mostrar as diferenças.
Mas não quero listar o nome dos arquivos, quero apenas que faça uma comparação dos diretórios e mostre as diferenças dos arquivos. Estes arquivos seriam `.cs`.

Exemplo:

```
string diretorio1 = "c:\teste"
string diretorio2 = "c:\teste2"
```

Vai fazer uma comparação dos dois diretórios e de todos os arquivos e trazer as diferenças.

Comment: O que você já fez? Qual sua dúvida específica?

Comment: Talvez o WinMerge ou um software de comparação de arquivos te ajude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer isto, cada uma com suas vantagens. Como não há restrições vou colocar o que provavelmente é a forma mais simples. Estou usando [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
var arquivo1 = File.ReadAllBytes(nomeArquivo1);
var arquivo2 = File.ReadAllBytes(nomeArquivo2);
WriteLine(arquivo1.SequenceEqual(arquivo2)); //mostra se é igual ou não
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ReadFile.cs).

Algumas melhorias podem ser feitas, como ir carregando o arquivo sob demanda. Sem carregar byte por byte, que ficaria muito lento, o ideal é ter um *buffer* de pelo menos 4096 bytes.

No momento de montar o *array*, ao invés de usar um *array* de bytes, poderia montar os bytes em conjuntos de 8 e armazenar em um *array* de `Int64` e compará-lo. A comparação será mais rápida, mas não sei o quanto o algoritmo como um todo seria mais rápido, tem que considerar o gasto com o *cast*, a lógica para montar isto, a carga dos dados que teria que ser um pouco diferente. Só testando para ter certeza qual seria mais rápido.

Se a performance for muito importante talvez o uso de ponteiros possa ajudar. Assim como evitar o LINQ que tem um pequeno *overhead*. Novamente, só testando para ter certeza.

Algumas verificações extras podem ser feitas se necessárias.

Para fazer um diferencial entre eles é bem mais complicado e é difícil fazer certo. [A Google já fez um *diff* antes](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/source/browse/trunk/csharp/DiffMatchPatch.cs) usando algoritmos conhecidos. Tem umas gambiarras já que é um *port*.

Tem outras perguntas aqui que mostra como varrer um diretório, é só adpatar ao algoritmo desejado:

- [Como buscar um arquivo em todas as pastas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75167/101)
- [Como unir vários arquivos texto em um só?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16704/101)
- [Como contar arquivos .xls / .xlsx na pasta com C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30797/101)

Comment: Bigown,
Eu gostaria que a comparação varresse o diretório, sendo assim, comparando todos os arquivos dentro do diretório.

Para entender melhor, eu tenho uma solution oficial em um diretório e uma solution local, quero comparar os dois e mostrar as diferenças dos arquivos .cs que possuem nestes diretórios.

 A ideia é mostrar se a solution local está igual a solution oficial.

Comment: Então sua pergunta está muito ampla, ela até deveria ser fechada, eu já ajudei alguma coisa. Quando vai fazer uma pergunta tem que ser específico, colocar o que já fez, onde está sua dúvida. Quando não dá detalhes, você dá margem para qualquer resposta. Pedir para fazer tudo para você não é legal. Estou dando o básico. Se tiver problemas específicos, poste novas perguntas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNass isso está mais com cara de versionamento.

Comment: Pessoal, a minha dúvida pode ser resolvida com o que falaram sobre usar software de comparação (beyond, winmerge), porém queria fazer a comparação em c#.

Comment: @GuilhermeNass, seguindo a dica do bigown e porque achei interessante a ideia, pensei que você poderia criar um um projeto público no github.